# Why won't Thunderbird completely delete emails?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I'm using Thunderbird v60 and I'm syncing with an IMAP email server. When I delete messages in Thunderbird, even though they appear to be deleted, they don't actually get deleted. When I go to my email via the web, I have to empty the trash to make them disappear.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Compact folders.
- Within "Preferences > Advanced > Config Editor...", change `mail.imap.expunge_after_delete` to `true`.
- Empty the trash folder.

Also, the All-Mail folder is showing more messages than are in all the combined folders and when I delete supposedly deleted messages they increase the All-Mail number.

[image: All Mail Folder?]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Who is the email service provider?  It sounds like you are doing your settings in Thunderbird, which controls Thunderbird behavior.  What the email service provider does with those settings depends on them.  Moving deleted messages to Trash is typical behavior.  Otherwise, the service providers would be dealing with endless requests for help recovering messages that users decide need to be undeleted.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently using Protonmail. However, I am not sure this helps as I have deleted the email in the trash from the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple way to fix this.

IMAP will synchronize and download mail for all subscribed folders on the server. Anything sent to the trash automatically goes to the All Mail folder on the server end, and will consequently be downloaded back into Thunderbird.

By going to the menu, file, Subscribe... Uncheck All-Mail solves the problem. This will stop all download trashed messages to the folder, and it will disappear in the view. Doing this will also prevent TB from storing deleted messages even after trash is emptied.

Every other checked folder you subscribed to will be visible, and less confusing.

By compacting the trash in TB after empty, the server will automatically purge them.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the mismatch of email counts... not having IMAP folders synced will hide their counts from your client but not the mail server, since the `All Mail` folder is generated by your mail provider it includes the emails in IMAP folders you haven't subscribed to. From the screenshot it appears you also don't have your `Trash` or `Spam` folders synced. So that's another possible source of disparity in the counts.

Regarding the failure to delete emails. Well... that's not Thunderbird's fault. Thunderbird sends a message to the IMAP provider to remove the message from the folder... but it's up to the IMAP provider how it does so. In this case it appears that the IMAP provider is simply moving the email to the `Trash` folder. This is actually really common and is typically seen as a useful feature. Most IMAP providers will also completely delete emails from the `Trash` folder automatically when they have been in the trash more than a certain amount of time (usually something like 30 days)... meaning that you never have to empty the trash folder yourself. And, because your don't appear to have your `Trash` folder synced... you only see this on the IMAP provider, not Thunderbird.

The solution to *all* of this is to simply [subscribe](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/imap-synchronization#w_configuring-synchronization-and-disk-space-usage) to every IMAP folder.

There is, however, one last "gotcha". Thunderbird uses `Trash` as the folder name for it's trash folder and `Spam` for the folder name of it's spam folder. If your IMAP provider uses a different name then you will simply have to live with duplicate trash and/or spam folders... one managed by your client and the other managed by your IMAP provider. Many email clients provide a way to change what the default folders are named in the client.  Thunderbird, afaik, is not one of those clients. There is [a rather hacky way](http://kb.mozillazine.org/IMAP_Trash_folder) to do so, for the trash folder at least, intended for advanced users. If this turns out to be an issue and it is important to you, you may want to explore other email clients.

Answer (score 0):

The secret to being happy with IMAP is lies in having patience and faith.

I landed on this discussion because I was having a similar issue with Thunderbird 91 on Linux Mint and Protonmail - I'm trying to cull my trash folder (Protonmail doesn't permanently delete emails from the trash after a certain period), deleting thousands of emails from Thunderbird, only to see them stubbornly reappear when I'd refresh Thunderbird's trash folder immediately. (Proton lets you delete only 50 at a time or ALL of them, so I had to do this from Thunderbird.)

You have to keep in mind that the web interface of your email provider is ALSO an IMAP client. Granted, it runs locally, so one would expect things to be snappier in terms of updating a folder but, alas, that's not necessarily the case.

Once I was able to get over some synchronization weirdness (webmail's trash showed some emails that weren't in Thunderbird's trash and vice-versa, so I had to do some manual work on both ends), I went little by little (e.g. deleting a few months worth of trashed emails at a time in Thunderbird) and "let it rest" (30 min or an hour), before refreshing either client to see if the deletions "stuck."

I had similar experiences with emClient on Windows with gmail.